# Python Tkinter: Adding A Horizontal Scrollbar To A Canvas With Pack()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have just begun working with Tkinter in an effort to build a GUI that has a vertically and horizontally scroll-able frame.

I managed to add the vertical scrollbar to the frame with the help of a canvas, but am struggling to understand why the horizontal scrollbar is not being properly added to the frame.

The following is my minimal reproducible example for you to see where my current progress is:

```
from tkinter import *

MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.geometry('1350x680')

GameFrame = Frame(MainWindow)

canvas = Canvas(GameFrame, bg="green")

canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

verticalBar = Scrollbar(GameFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
verticalBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
horizontalBar = Scrollbar(GameFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
horizontalBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=verticalBar.set,
                 xscrollcommand=horizontalBar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(
    scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL)))

canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

RoundFrame = Frame(canvas, bg="green")

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=RoundFrame,
                     anchor="nw", width=1900, height=1900)

GameFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

horizontalPos = 0
verticalPos = 0
for i in range(10):
    Label(RoundFrame, text="A", font=('Helvetica 40 bold')).grid(
        row=0, column=0, padx=(horizontalPos, 0), pady=(verticalPos, 0))
    horizontalPos += 170
    verticalPos += 50

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

I have created a window with the canvas I have.

There are two frames involved in this process: GameFrame and RoundFrame

I want to position labels on "RoundFrame".

Please assist me in understanding what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

I have created a window with the canvas I have.

There are two frames involved in this.

I want to make labels appear on the "RoundFrame".

Right now only seven of the ten "A" labels appear because the horizontal scrollbar has not been added properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the horizontal scrollbar to be below the canvas using `pack`, the easiest solution is to pack the scrollbar before packing the canvas. This is easier if you separate your widget creation from widget layout, and group all layout commands for siblings.

```
verticalBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
horizontalBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

This is because the packer allocates an entire side of the available empty space for each widget. When you pack the canvas to the left before the other widgets, nothing will be able to be placed above or below it since it takes up the entire left side of the window.